# Vue convert image into base64

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, base64

I want to convert an local image to base64. The **reader.readAsDataURL** does not work. I always get an undefined for the rawImg var. The value for the file var, are the metadata from the file I try to upload.
[image]

HTML:

```
<input
  type="file"
  accept="image/jpeg/*"
  @change="uploadImage()"
/>
```

JS:

```
uploadImage() {
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader()

  const rawImg = reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  console.log(file)
  console.log(rawImg)
}
```

Comment: `.readAsDataURL` is asynchronous

Comment: tip: loop `[0]` walla.. multi-file uploads

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work if you set the image directly from `readAsDataURL`, which returns `undefined` always.  Instead, use the `onloadend` event:

```js
let rawImg;
const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = () => {
   rawImg = reader.result;
   console.log(rawImg);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as above but a tad bit shorter approach.

```
<input type="file" @change="createImage" />

function createImage(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => (console.log(reader.result));
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.target.files[0]);
}
```